# Is pipelining possible in ESPER CEP?

Tags: complex-event-processing, esper

I am new to ESPER.
I just want to know if pipelining is possible in Esper.

I have a listener which monitors temperature difference. Suppose there are two cases :

- 1. Difference in temperatures is 10 degrees.
- 2. spike in temperature is above 2%.

Now I have to run these checks in two separate EPstatments on the same event having same listener. 
For example if it receives a temperature difference of 30 then both the queries will return true and corresponding listener will execute, so there is no reason for both of them raising 2 alerts.

So, how can we design so that if first statement is true and raises an alert the second should not execute.

Comment: As I know, Esper EPL support `if .. then .. else` like SQL. Do you need that instead of execute 2 queries?

Comment: Thanks@Manh Le, but  I don't want to make changes to the queries. I know I can do that. I want to know how can we use pipelining in esper if we have a scenario like this?

Comment: Suggest to drop the "pipeline" tag and the "pipelining" terminology. You are talking about requirements that are duplicate suppression. This is often done via "output first" or one of the "first" data windows. For example: `insert into AlertStream select ...; insert into AlertStream select ...; select * from Alertstream.win:first_unique(...)'

Comment: Thanks @goodie! :) It is working!

Comment: This is fine! But in this case it inserts both the events in a stream. What if  don't want to evaluate the second statement if the first statement is true (without using a common AlertStream)? Is there any way? Please, help?